# Ruby: now.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X %z") gives wrong time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hello guys I'm using a Ruby script to send error mails (https://github.com/u-ichi/fluent-plugin-mail/blob/master/lib/fluent/plugin/out_mail.rb) which relies on Net::SMTP. The time is obtained using "Time::now.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X %z")",

```
...
smtp.send_mail(<<EOS, @from, @to.split(/,/), @cc.split(/,/), @bcc.split(/,/))
   Date: #{Time::now.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X %z")}
   From: #{@from}
   To: #{@to}
   Cc: #{@cc}
   Bcc: #{@bcc}
   Subject: #{subject}
   Mime-Version: 1.0
   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
   #{body}
EOS
smtp.finish
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting the mails with a wrong time. I don't know how Time::now.strftime works but I guess they pick the time from the server? I'm on CentOS and checked the "date" of the server and found no error...

Is there other way to get the time?

Comment: Does `date +%Z` output the time zone you are expecting?

Comment: And yes, the time zone is equal to the server time zone by default.

Comment: Time::now is `Returns a Time object initialized to the current system time.` And documentation for `strftime`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Time.html#method-i-strftime

Comment: So if you want UTC time for emails, you can do something like `Time::now.utc.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X %z")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should convert this time in a specific timezone. like:

```
time_zone = ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new(your_desire_time_zone)
converted_time = time.in_time_zone(time_zone)
```

or convert in UTC

```
converted_time = Time.now.utc
```

Then try to use `strftime`

```
converted_time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %X %z")
```

For more details, find [here](http://apidock.com/rails/Time/in_time_zone). Thanks.

Comment: I don't think he uses Rails, so `ActiveSupport` will probably not be there.

Comment: OP accepted it, so perhaps no Rails, but I don't think ActiveSupport requires Rails use, either way.  Probably could add `ActiveSupport` tag on the question.

Comment: yes i'm not with rails, but converted_time = Time.now.utc totally worked! thanks a lot mate